# How to prove roots of several univariate polynomials is a solution of a multivariable polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

When I study the existence of certain spherical polygon, I have encountered the following problem.

Let $\gamma$ and $\delta$ be angles such that 
$1216\cos^6\gamma-1056\cos^4\gamma+84\cos^2\gamma-1=0, \ \cos\gamma\approx -0.8839453420007384$.
$1216\sin^6\gamma-2592\sin^4\gamma+1620\sin^2\gamma-243=0, \ 
\sin\gamma\approx-0.4675902397989036$.
$1216\cos^6\delta-2496\cos^4\delta+1668\cos^2\delta-361=0,\ 
\cos\delta\approx 0.8469176972278768$.
$1216\sin^6\delta-1152\sin^4\delta+324\sin^2\delta-27=0,\
\sin\delta\approx
0.5317240018301108$.

When I put $\cos\gamma=-0.8839453420007384$, $\sin\gamma=-0.4675902397989036$, $\cos\delta= 0.8469176972278768$ and $\sin\delta=0.5317240018301108$ into 
$(\dfrac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6}-\dfrac{\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{4}{3\sqrt{3}})\sin\delta\sin\gamma+(\dfrac{5\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{18}-\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{4}{9})\cos\delta\sin\gamma$
$-(\dfrac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{2\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{2})\cos\gamma\sin\delta+(\dfrac{5\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6}+\dfrac{\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{2\sqrt{3}})\cos\delta\cos\gamma$, I get $5.551115123125783\times 10^{-17}$.

> How to prove/disprove 
>   $(\dfrac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6}-\dfrac{\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{4}{3\sqrt{3}})\sin\delta\sin\gamma+(\dfrac{5\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{18}-\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{4}{9})\cos\delta\sin\gamma$
>   $-(\dfrac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{2\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{2})\cos\gamma\sin\delta+(\dfrac{5\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}{6}+\dfrac{\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{2\sqrt{3}})\cos\delta\cos\gamma=0$.

**Remark:** In order to make sure there is no typo, I include the picture of the expression and the computation result in wxmaxima:

[image]

where $cga=\cos\gamma$, $sga=\sin\gamma$, $cde=\cos\delta$ and $sde=\sin\delta$.
Note that $2 \  3^{3/2}=2\times 3^{3/2}$.

Comment: Have you checked your conjecture with higher numerical precision?

Comment: Another remark is that in principle, you can compute $\sin \gamma$, $\sin \delta$, etc, in closed form, by solving cubics.

Comment: In principle, resultants should give a way to do this; however, with such a long expression, it would likely take a long time to write it out. I suspect there's some relatively simple trig identity behind this, if it's true.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, I have tried to checked my higher numerical precision. However, wxmaxima seems to take around 16 decimal places in the process even when I put those cosine values and sine values with precision of 60 or more decimal places in the beginning. I think I may need to use another program to verify my conjecture. However, wxmaxima seems to take around 16 decimal places in the process even when I put those cosine values and sine values with precision of 60 or more decimal places in the beginning. I think I may use another program to verify my conjecture.

Comment: At first, I think I can prove/disprove it easily by writing out those sine/cosine values explicitly via solving cubic. Since those equations are cubic polynomials with 3 real roots in square of sine/cosine of $\gamma$ or $\delta$, even one can compute $sin\gamma$ in closed form, but it must be involved imaginary number i and look quite complication. That is why I takes it as the last resort. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @user44191, Can you elaborate more about how to apply the resultants method to my problem? Do you have any good references about how to prove/disprove the above problem? Thank you.

Comment: Does your expression get any nicer if you rewrite everything in terms of $\sin(\gamma \pm \delta)$, $\cos(\gamma \pm\delta)$ using the sum and difference identities?

Comment: In Maxima, multiple precision floating point numbers should be entered with the notation #.##########b# (big floats) instead of #.####### or #.#########e# (regular floats). Use _bfloat(...)_ to evaluate known constants and functions as big floats. The global variable _fpprec_ controls the number of digits kept while working with big floats.

Comment: I think you can convert this to polynomial equations, that is, introduce sin(gamma), etc as quantities defined via equations, and then use a Groebner basis approach.

Comment: @JamesCheung The idea for resultants is just that everything involved is an algebraic number, so the left-hand side can in principle be expressed as the root of a polynomial using resultants (e.g. $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is a root of the polynomial $\text{Res}_y(y^2 - 2, (x - y)^2 - 3)$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a standard problem of algebraic geometry, which admits a completely algorithmic solution. We note that $\cos\frac{2\pi}9$ is a root $x$ of the equation $1 - 6 x + 8 x^3 = 0$. The rest of the task a computer algebra program can do easily, as seen in the following image of a Mathematica notebook, confirming your conjecture by giving the exact (zero) value of your big expression:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a more hands-on answer than the previous one; it is based on resultants.

Here we again note that 
$$x_*:=\cos\tfrac{2\pi}9$$ 
is a root of the equation 
$$p_1(x):=1 - 6 x + 8 x^3 = 0.$$
Next, using the formula $\cos^2=\frac1{1+\tan^2}$, we see that 
$$V_*:=\tan\gamma$$ 
is a root of the equation 
$$P_2(V):=243 - 891 V^2 + 81 V^4 - V^6 = 0$$ 
and 
$$T_*:=\tan\delta$$ 
is a root of the equation 
$$P_3(T):=27 - 243 T^2 + 585 T^4 - 361 T^6 = 0.$$ 
Moreover, the pair $(x_*,y_*)$ with 
$$y_*:=\sin\tfrac{2\pi}9$$ 
is a root of the equation 
$$p_4(x,y):=x^2+y^2 - 1 = 0.$$ 
We have to show that the quadruple $(x_*,y_*,V_*,T_*)$ is a root $(x,y,V,T)$ of the equation 
$$L:=L(x,y,V,T):=\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{5 y}{6}\right)+V\left(\frac{5 x}{18}-\frac{y}{6
   \sqrt{3}}-\frac{4}{9}\right)-T\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)+T V \left(-\frac{x}{6
   \sqrt{3}}+\frac{y}{6}-\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}}\right)=0;$$
this simplification of the big expression in question is crucial, as it allows to reduce the calculations to a feasible level.

Let us now quote the following [property of the resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Zeros): 
"The resultant of two polynomials with coefficients in an integral domain is zero if and only if they have a common root in an algebraically closed field containing the coefficients."

Consider successively the resultants
$$r_1(c,x,V,T):=R(L(x,y,V,T)-c,p_4(x,y),y),$$
$$r_2(c,V,T):=R(r_1(c,x,V,T),p_1(x),x),$$
$$r_3(c,T):=R(r_2(c,V,T),P_2(V),V),$$
$$r_4(c):=R(r_3(c,T),P_3(T),T),$$
where $R(P,Q,w)$ denotes the resultant of polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with respect to a variable $w$. (It takes about 30 sec for Mathematica to compute each of the resultants $r_3(c,T)$ and $r_4(c)$.)

It follows from the quoted property of the resultant that the real number $L(x_*,y_*,V_*,T_*)$ must be in the set of all real roots of the polynomial $r_4(c)$.  In fact, $r_4(c)$ has the root $0$ (of multiplicity $3$), whereas all the other $213$ real roots of $r_4(c)$ are $>1/2$ in absolute value. However, a direct numerical calculation shows that $|L(x_*,y_*,V_*,T_*)|\le1/2$. 
Thus, $L(x_*,y_*,V_*,T_*)=0$, as desired.